# How long does it take for someone to reach the limit of the Secret Training?

Tags: final-fantasy-type-0-hd

Whenever I send Queen to do the Secret Training, generally after 24 hours she only levels up 2 - 3 times, but once I left her for 72 hours (over the course of a weekend) and this didn't change.

My Main Party is Queen (Lv. 72), Carter (Lv. 51) and Rem (Lv. 45), so mostly everyone else is sitting on around Level 26 - 27. I was thinking of bringing them up to around Rem's level using the Secret Training so I can play Persona 2 Eternal Punishment at the same time.

So I am wondering, how long does it take for someone to reach the limit of the Secret Training, so i know when to load the game back up and end the session before restarting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum amount of experience a character gain through [Secret Training](http://www.ign.com/wikis/final-fantasy-type-0/Secret_Training) is capped at 24 hours

> Note that the max amount of EXP can be gained within 24 hours

You can accelerate the Secret Training through this process:

1. Initiate Secret Training
2. Navigate to PS4/X1 manual Date Settings
3. Increase the current date by 1 day
4. Reload your Type-0 save to receive XP